# Python 3: How do I properly append a number from a line that has numbers and strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

Right now, I'm working with several lines that follow a format of [longitude, latitude] date time text and I'm not sure how to pull just the latitude and just the longitude.

What I tried doing was splitting the overall file into lines (this part worked fine), then splitting the lines into words (which worked), but now I'm unable to pull longitude as a float as I'm getting a Traceback ValueError where it's saying that it can't convert a string to a float.

At first I thought the problem was that words (in this case, WordZ) line looked something like `"['45.696179999999998,', '-122.51231420000001]', '3', '2011-09-01', '17:06:53',[...]"` and so logically trying to pull the long as a float by making `long = float(WordZ[0])` was impossible because WordZ ended with a comma.

So I tried doing `#long = float(WordZ[0].rstrip(","))`. But I'm still getting the same can't convert string to float error.

And to make matters worse, I have no idea why this is happening because the comma is for sure getting removed as per the output box:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/claym/Desktop/Assignment3/assign3.py", line 28, in <module>
         long = float(WordZ[0].rstrip(","))
.ValueError: could not convert string to float:     
    41.29866963

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What do I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: From what I can deduce from the little code you provided you are working with an array or multidimensional array. If you have an entry contained within single or double quotes it will be interpreted as a string. Can you remove the single or double quotes? So it would read as EX: 1, 2, 3.5 instead of ’1’, ’2’, ’3.5’. Hope that helps.

Comment: So do you have a  text file with lines following the format: `[latitude, longitude] ,date, time, text` and you want to get latitude/longitude for each line?

Comment: Wait, just realized it didn't work once I tried to convert it to float. @ArtemisFowl yeah, that's how the textfile looks. I'm pretty much supposed to evaluate each line and assign points. I've got a rough idea of how I'd do the points assigning part, but I have no idea how to grab the latitude as a float since I keep getting ValueErrors that say I can't convert a string to floats even though the output box looks like: 39.811711539999997

41.683533250000004

45.696179999999998

19.372430619999999

45.498773239999998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = open('C:/6T1VkYUj.txt')  # where the file is

lat = []  # list to store values
lon = []  # list to store values
# counter = 0   #optional in case you want to be sure that all the records where processed

for record in file:
    # counter += 1
    record = record.replace('[',"")  # removing the left bracket
    fields0 = record.split(']')  # spliting by right bracket
    fields1 = fields0[0].split(',')  # spliting the first fields0 that your data is in by comma
    lat.append(float(fields1[0]))  # filling the lists
    lon.append(float(fields1[1]))   # filling the lists

# print(counter)  #optional in case you want to be sure that all the records where processed
# print(len(lat))  #optional in case you want to be sure that all the records where processed
# print(len(lon))  #optional in case you want to be sure that all the records where processed
print(lat)
print(lon)
```

Comment: I see what you did, and I've done something similar, but when I went to implement this, I found something that I wasn't aware was happening (hopefully it's the cause of my problems). So the file is being split by the lines (I did line = file.split("\n"), but I just realized that this is causing the variable that handles each line to treat each line as a singular item in an array. No wonder it's not working! 
But then, when I went to test this theory by doing print(line[3]), it said that the list index is out of range even though there are much more than 4 lines in this file.

Comment: If you like upload a copy of the file somewhere so we can access it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6T1VkYUj

That's the list of content I'm supposed to be working with. The output shows that the brackets and commas aren't getting removed for some reason

Comment: Worked for me (Python 3.4)

Comment: Just tried it again without implementing your code into mine, and it worked, which means that I screwed up somewhere in the implementation. I wish I was better at this lol, oh well, time to figure out where I messed up. Thank you for your help Ignatios (and for helping me to further isolate the problem I created)!

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IGNATIOS!!! I went back and kept fiddling with the code that I wrote to figure out why the program wasn't working even though I was implementing your code. I found the problem, fixed it, and now the program works as desired! Thank you so much :) I have no idea why it was a problem in the first place, but now I know that what I did was wrong. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

depending on exactly how your txt file was formatted, this could work:

```
file=open("info.txt", "r")
linestxt=file.read().split("\n")
lines=[]
for i in linestxt:
    j=i.split("]")
    i=j[0]+"]"
    exec("line=["+i+"]")
    lines.append(line)
lats=[]
longs=[]
for i in line:
    lats.append(i[0][0])
    longs.append(i[0][1])
```

so really `[lat, long]` would have to be valid syntax (`lat` and `long` would both have to be `int`, `str` or `float` type. (or any other data type))

Comment: Highky insecure, that's some high quality code injection here

Comment: It didn't work :/ I'll copy paste the error I got into pastebin so the formatting isn't eligible:

https://pastebin.com/n1u7FirC

I tried fixing the syntax but wasn't able to

Comment: @Linus you need commas between items in the list

Comment: You mean the list that I'm parsing through? Here is what I'm using: https://pastebin.com/6T1VkYUj

Unfortunately, I have to work with it as it is :/

Comment: Think i've fixed it